# SMPS Transformer - Secondary voltage rating

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I am designing isolated flyback converter with input voltage range 40VDC-110VDC, 5V/6A output. I am struggling with finding appropriate transformer since each and every one I found have lower primary voltage rating or lower secondary current rating.

My taught was to connect the transformers in series in order do get higher input range, but then my output voltage doubles accordingly.

If using i.e. http://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/750311797.pdf could I get 5V output using regulation loop?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Wind your own is my advice.

Comment: http://www.premiermag.com/html/product-family/power-magnetics.html

Comment: Haven't found the one I was looking for. Tnx for the link, anyhow :D

Answer (score 1):

Windings 1-3 and 2-4 are the same. The rest are "12V" windings.

If you connect the 1-3 and 2-4 in series the turns ratio will change from 2.5:1 to 5:1 and the output voltage will go down by half.

You should be able to put the secondary winding in parallel or in series depending on what you want.

Comment: Could I connect auxiliary primary winding to 18-100V input in order to increase inductance?